# ¿Cómo puedo configurar el proceso de construcción del bot de Deepshield?

Tags: java, github, maven

Tengo un proyecto open source [en github](https://github.com/javatlacati/regextester) que es un [plugin ya publicado](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11370-dukescript-java-regex-tester) para el ide [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) que construyo con la ayuda de [maven](/questions/tagged/maven).

## Proceso de construcción

Para poder compilar necesito usar las librerías del IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition así que como parte de mi integración contínua, usando [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci) para el build en linux y [appveyor](/questions/tagged/appveyor) para el build en windows; descargo una versión específica desde la página oficial y declaro las librerías jars que necesito con el ámbito de dependencias de sistema mediante maven.

Es un maven multimódulo, para mi parte del plugin de IDEa tengo los plugins de la siguiente manera:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                            <destFileName>springloaded.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <type>zip</type>
            <classifier>webpages</classifier>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/org/javapro/regextester</outputDirectory>
            <includes>*/**</includes>
            <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-idea-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/${env.VERSION}/ideaIC-${env.VERSION}.zip</url>
                            <unpack>true</unpack>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

## Detalles del problema

Deepshield me creó un issue con el titulo

> DepShield encountered errors while building your project

Y dentro un texto con un link al mensaje de error, este es el mensaje de error que referencia

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.javapro:regextester-idea:jar:1.0.3
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.jetbrains:util:jar refers to a non-existing file /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/lib/lib/util.jar @ org.javapro:regextester-idea:[unknown-version], /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/pom.xml, line 98, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.jetbrains:platform-core-ui:jar refers to a non-existing file /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/lib/lib/platform-core-ui.jar @ org.javapro:regextester-idea:[unknown-version], /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/pom.xml, line 105, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.jetbrains:openapi:jar refers to a non-existing file /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/lib/lib/openapi.jar @ org.javapro:regextester-idea:[unknown-version], /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/pom.xml, line 112, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.jetbrains:platform:jar refers to a non-existing file /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/lib/lib/platform-api.jar @ org.javapro:regextester-idea:[unknown-version], /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/pom.xml, line 119, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.jetbrains:annotations:jar refers to a non-existing file /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/lib/lib/annotations.jar @ org.javapro:regextester-idea:[unknown-version], /var/sonatype/defender/client-idea/pom.xml, line 126, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] regextester
[INFO] regextester JavaScript Libraries
[INFO] automatonosgi
[INFO] generex OSGi Bundle
[INFO] regextester General Client Code
[INFO] regextester Client for Web
[INFO] regextester Client for NetBeans
[INFO] regextester Client for Idea
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building regextester 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ regextester-pom ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /var/sonatype/defender/dependencies.txt
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building regextester JavaScript Libraries 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ regextester-js ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /var/sonatype/defender/dependencies.txt
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building automatonosgi 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ automatonosgi ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /var/sonatype/defender/dependencies.txt
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building generex OSGi Bundle 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ generex ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /var/sonatype/defender/dependencies.txt
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building regextester General Client Code 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ regextester ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /var/sonatype/defender/dependencies.txt
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building regextester Client for Web 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ regextester-web ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /var/sonatype/defender/dependencies.txt
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building regextester Client for NetBeans 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ regextester-nb ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /var/sonatype/defender/dependencies.txt
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building regextester Client for Idea 1.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ regextester-idea ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] regextester ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.445 s]
[INFO] regextester JavaScript Libraries ................... SUCCESS [  0.270 s]
[INFO] automatonosgi ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.292 s]
[INFO] generex OSGi Bundle ................................ SUCCESS [  0.013 s]
[INFO] regextester General Client Code .................... SUCCESS [  0.030 s]
[INFO] regextester Client for Web ......................... SUCCESS [  0.070 s]
[INFO] regextester Client for NetBeans .................... SUCCESS [  0.299 s]
[INFO] regextester Client for Idea ........................ FAILURE [  0.007 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.620 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-19T09:14:50Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/47M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) on project regextester-idea: Cannot build project dependency graph: Could not resolve nor collect following dependencies: [com.jetbrains:util:jar:1.0 (system), com.jetbrains:platform-core-ui:jar:1.0 (system), com.jetbrains:openapi:jar:1.0 (system), com.jetbrains:platform:jar:1.0 (system), com.jetbrains:annotations:jar:1.0 (system)]: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.javapro:regextester-idea:jar:1.0.3: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.javapro:regextester:jar:1.0.3, org.javapro:generex:jar:1.0.3, org.javapro:automatonosgi:jar:1.0.3, org.javapro:regextester-js:jar:1.0.3, com.jetbrains:util:jar:1.0, com.jetbrains:platform-core-ui:jar:1.0, com.jetbrains:openapi:jar:1.0, com.jetbrains:platform:jar:1.0, com.jetbrains:annotations:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.javapro:regextester:jar:1.0.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :regextester-idea
```

El problema es que deepshield no descargó nunca el IntelliJ IDEA Community para sacarle las dependencias.

## que solución busco

Quisiera personalizar el proceso de construcción de Deepshield o en su defecto hallar la forma de que maven mismo me solvente estos problemas.

## Actualización

Por mi log veo que

```
maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree
```

Es el comando que está tratando de llamar primero en vez de un install, ¿Existe alguna fase específica de ese plugin?¿A pesar de que la descarga la hago con maven en la fase `validate` es posible que se esté ejecutando otra fase antes y por eso de error?